# Which values can singer.write_records() take for its records parameter and how are they processed?

Tags: python, dictionary, generator, singer-io

When using the `singer.write_records()` method we pass a stream id as a string and a record as dict, for example:

```
singer.write_records(
      stream_name="example_stream", 
      records={"product1": "val1", "product2": "val2", "shop": "example_shop"}
)
```

But I have seen code where we pass a generator object to the records parameter instead of a dictionary, for example:

```
singer.write_records(
    stream_name="products",
    records=({**item, "shop": shop}
        for item in retrieve_products(shop))
)
```

Why is this possible? Where does the singer spec explicitly define which arguments the `write_records()` can take? How does the method process the data passed to the records field? I've looked up the singer specification but couldn't find any definition of `write_records()`. I also tried running `help(singer.write_records())` in the Python console, but the information printed wasn't helpful.

Comment: What API is this?  Where is this code from?

Comment: https://github.com/singer-io/getting-started/blob/master/docs/SPEC.md

Comment: One would think that with a name like `write_records`, that it writes multiple records.  And some sample code seems to confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

The singer spec is really just guidelines for the structure of messages (i.e. RECORD, SCHEMA, STATE) for communicating between a tap/target, it doesn’t have any requirements on the actual code that sends those messages, and technically Python isn’t a requirement. Check out Meltanos Singer [spec docs](https://hub.meltano.com/singer/spec) for a better spec description. I believe the code you’re referring to is from the [singer-python](https://github.com/singer-io/singer-python) library which is a common utility library (although I’d check out the [Meltano singer SDK](https://gitlab.com/meltano/sdk) for something more up to date). The [write_records](https://github.com/singer-io/singer-python/blob/66688d736fa699beeed63af91db2fdc1f8914bb1/singer/messages.py#L240) method looks like it just expects an iterable for the records parameter, so your dictionary is being iterated key by key or a generator will have one record retrieved on each iteration.